# Error after calling Firebase Cloud Function from Angular app

Tags: angular, firebase, https, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-404

I am trying to call a Firebase cloud function **from** my Angular project. I use the AngularFire library throughout my project, and use the `functions.https.onCall` trigger in my function.

The function has already been tested locally and works perfectly fine. I have also successfully deployed it to my Firebase project.

The error occurs when I attempt to call the cloud function from my app using the following:

```
const foo = this.AngularFireFunctions.httpsCallable("foo");
foo({
    // data
  })
    .toPromise()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

I then obtain the following three errors in my Chrome devTool:

> Access to fetch at 'https://europe-west2-nemo-dev-1b0bc.cloudfunctions.net/generateSwipeStack' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
POST https://europe-west2-nemo-dev-1b0bc.cloudfunctions.net/generateSwipeStack net::ERR_FAILED
```

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: internal
Error: internal
    at new HttpsErrorImpl (index.cjs.js:58)
    at _errorForResponse (index.cjs.js:153)
    at Service.<anonymous> (index.cjs.js:544)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:373)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:135)
    at zone.js:1274
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:407)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1215)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165)
    at zone.js:1277
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:407)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27424)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:179)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:583)
```

I am currently in the development process, so I am using `ionic serve` and hence running my app on localhost.

Here is what my app.module.ts file looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from "@ionic/angular";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {
  AngularFireFunctionsModule,
  REGION,
  ORIGIN,
} from "@angular/fire/functions";

import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

import { pageTransition } from "./shared/animations/page-transition.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot({ navAnimation: pageTransition }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: REGION, useValue: "europe-west2" },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to enable CORS in your Cloud Functions code. Searching for the error message should give you a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-functions%5d%20Response%20to%20preflight%20request%20doesn%27t%20pass%20access%20control%20check%3a%20No%20%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27%20header%20is%20present%20on%20the%20requested%20resource

Comment: Thanks! Enabling CORS for the onRequest cloud function seems straightforward, but what about for onCall?

Comment: How are you hosting your app ?