# Unable to retrieve the user-facing name for the "Runtimes" column

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Today suddenly the Google Cloud Functions page started showing the error in the screenshort below and also a weird section to sign up for Trial; which was never shown before.

This only happens on one of the projects, the other is completely fine.

I noticed that calls to functions in this project fail with `net::ERR_FAILED` and CORS error(because the server is down I guess).

[image]

Comment: please edit your question with more detailed information. Try using an alternative browser and check?Also  check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619036/local-firebase-web-app-tries-non-local-cloud-functions) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969165/error-after-calling-firebase-cloud-function-from-angular-app)

Comment: As your issue is fixed by enabling billing,please accept your answer and for the follow-up question who or what disabled billing you may raise a new question

Comment: Sure, must wait 26 more minutes to accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused due to the billing plan getting downgraded. Upgrading the billing plan again(enabling billing) fixed the issue.

Now who or what disabled billing, we don't know yet!